# Web user interface. Add new item and list of items

Tags: user-interface

I need your opinion on the following question. It's need to implement the administration web interface to add\change\remove\display system users. I need to display all users and controls for user adding/changing. What is the common pattern in web for this situation: create one page or create two separate pages for displaying and adding/changing users?

Thanks, sorry for some possible oddness (:

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look at common desktop applications, like a file manager. Usually you see a list of files and a (toolbar) button to create a new one, that opens a dialog panel if necessary, in which you can enter basic properties to start with.

Comment: Yes, in desctop application it is the common way to implement such functionality. But what about web?... =)

Comment: @w1z: Why should web applications differ from desktop apps? Just try to implement common conventions everywhere, so users will have the least difficulty to get accustomed to new applications.

Answer (score 1):

I like to have a view page that has the list of users, with the most common properties.  Each user will have an view link, which will bring you to a page that displays the complete set of user properties, and will also allow you to edit the user on this page.

Comment: I always thought as well, but now I began to have doubts :))

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for the same information and eventually found [a page depicting various approaches for user interfaces that allow users to add/edit/view items in lists](http://www.21techmag.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18%3aweb-ui-techniques&Itemid=32).

I can't hope to convey the same amount of information from the article here, but just in case the article disappears here are some of the techniques discussed:

- Show identifying information for each item in a dropdown.  Show populated fields when the user selects an existing item.  Show the same form with empty fields when the user adds a new item.
- Show a subset of information for each item in a table.  Show populated fields when the user selects an existing item.  Show the same form with empty fields when the user adds a new item.  The example depicts the form on the same page.
- Show the data for each item in a table and allow user to directly modify the data in each row of the table (with buttons to add/remove items).

In all cases, you can probably improve usability with JavaScript/Ajax assuming your target users will have this enabled.

Comment: FYI - link is broken